# why i am not getting output(javascript)?

Tags: javascript

```js
var counter = document.getElementsByClassName("counter");
var followers = document.getElementsByClassName("followers");
var count = 1;
setInterval(() => {

  count++;
  counter.innerHTML = count;

}, 3000);
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <span class="counter">0</span>
  <span class="followers">0</span>

</div>
```

In the above code i want to print the count number instead of my html content but not getting proper
result what's the issue in that.If you got it, please let me know

Comment: But you're not logging anything. The value increments, but you have to `console.log()` it

Comment: @JeremyThille - I think they're expecting the assignment to `innerHTML` to show something.

Comment: Indeed, stupid me. In this case, it's a duplicate. `getElement-S-ByClassName` return several elementS (hence the name), and one can't define `.innerHTML` directly on several elements, they have to be iterated.

Comment: Yup, already marked it.

Comment: @JeremyThille yes i need to chnge html content by this code

Comment: what is answer to get this